# xcode 6 missing main.swift file for new projects

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I reinstalled Xcode 6 after not being able to get the usual ctrl-click help.
Now, whenever I create a new Xcode project for OS X Cocoa Application, the main.swift file is no longer in the supporting files as it used to be. I have 2 partitions and Mavericks on one, Yosemite on the other.
Can anybody please tell me what is going on and how to get around it?
This is my first question, be free to point me out any mistakes in it as well, please.
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a `main.swift` file. The main (heh) purpose of that file is to call [`NSApplicationMain()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSApplicationMain), the function that gets a Cocoa app up and running. But, since every app needs to do that, Apple added a less-boilerplate way of doing things.

Now, you just need to label your app delegate class with the `@NSApplicationMain` attribute. Then Xcode will build in the right hooks to get your app launched into its main run loop with an instance of your chosen class as `NSApp`'s delegate. The new project templates do this, which is why you don't need a `main.swift` anymore. (It also frees you from needing to designate the app delegate in a main nib, which is useful for apps using OS X storyboards.)

Of course, if you want to customize your app setup a bit more—say, by running some code before the run loop kicks off, or with a custom `NSApplication` subclass—you can still create a `main.swift` file and call `NSApplicationMain()` yourself. (If you do, be sure to also remove the `@NSApplicationMain` attribute from your app delegate class.)

Comment: Thanks very much. You were quite clear. I think I'm ready to proceed my learning with one less worry... Sorry for not voting you up, but I'm so new here that I don't even have 15 points of reputation! When I get there, I'll come back. Best regards, Artur Pinheiro

Comment: One very minor correction.  When I read the sentence that reads "Now, you just need to label your map delegate class with the @NSApplicationMain attribute." I was confused at first.  Of course, "map delegate" should be "AppDelegate."

`@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {`