# Why does modern Xcode generate projects with UIApplicationMain outside of autorelease pool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, nsautoreleasepool

If I remember correctly, back in the days Xcode used to generate the `main` function something like this (at least for iOS applications):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]);
    }        
}
```

I.e. `UIApplicationMain` function was wrapped inside of `@autoreleasepool`. However I noticed that currently Xcode no longer does that:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    NSString * appDelegateClassName;
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Setup code that might create autoreleased objects goes here.
        appDelegateClassName = NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]);
    }
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, appDelegateClassName);
}
```

So, `UIApplicationMain` is outside of the autorelease pool by default nowadays. Is there any official changelog/paper that explains why the latter implementation is now preferred over the former one?

Comment: Related: [Why does a new Objective-C project's boilerplate contain an autorelease pool block, but a new Swift project doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961767/why-does-a-new-objective-c-projects-boilerplate-contain-an-autorelease-pool-blo)